# How to remove bars for those bars with zero value in Chartjs bar chart?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, bar-chart, chart.js

Even if the bars have value of zero in bar chart created using chartjs, they still show a visible bar. This is misleading for my purpose and I would like to have it removed and show nothing there (meaning that, I still want to show labels  with zero value but not the bar). I tried changing min value of y-axis but it doesn't make a difference. The image below shows this problem for columns 56, 60 and 78. Is there a way to get rid of this? Thanks!

[image: bar chart]

And here is my script:

```
<div>
  <canvas id="canvas_bar" height="250", width = "300" ></canvas>
</div>

<script>
    var barChartData = {
        labels : [56, 60, 78, 90],
        datasets : [
        {   fillColor : "rgba(139,0,0,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            data : [20.0, 0, 0, 50]  },

        {   fillColor : "rgba(1,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            data : [0, 0.0, 40.0, 10]  }
        ]
    }
    window.onload = function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas_bar").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
            animation: false,
            responsive : false,
            barValueSpacing : 15,
            scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can you try in jsfiddle ?

Comment: Add this in your options : `barStrokeWidth: 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `barStrokeWidth` value is 2.

Just add this :

```
barStrokeWidth:0,
```

or :

```
barShowStroke : false,
```

In your options.

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-chart-options

> //Boolean - If there is a stroke on each bar
>
> barShowStroke : true,
>
> //Number - Pixel width of the bar stroke
>
> barStrokeWidth : 2,

Comment: Awesome. `barShowStroke` does the trick here! Setting `barStrokeWidth` to zero still shows color on the x-axis line. Thanks! I would have preferred to have stroke around bars. Is there a way to have strokes on sides except for the bottom side?

Comment: Can you try in Jsfiddle ?

Comment: @user2267379- After playing around a little, I see absence of stroke actually makes chart nicer and cleaner! Setting `barShowStroke` to false works for me. Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE: With current version > 4.3.x. Dataset property *barStrokeWidth* is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

update December 2021:

- `barStrokeWidth` is deprecated.
- I used `inflateAmount: 0` (default value is `auto`) and it fixed the issue for me

docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-properties

Comment: `inflateAmount: 0` worked for me! Needed to hide 0 value bars in a stacked bar | chart.js@3.7.1

Answer (score 0):

if `barShowStroke : true`

not working try to

```
barRadius: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can add `skipNull` property to dataset objects. And bars where value is `null` or `undefined` won't take any space.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.2.0/charts/bar.html